# Sharing files or content with 3rd party activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-gallery, android-permissions

I have a simple question but can't seem to find the answer anywhere I look online.

I have an activity A that downloads files from the internet and puts them to a local folder obtained by getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() which points to: "/data/data/com.myapp.android/files"

Now when the user selects a file I want to show its content and for that I do the following:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, type);

Intent intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");
startActivity(intentChooser);
```

When this executes the user is presented with the Open File dialog and after they select "Gallery" the Gallery activity appears with nothing on it.

Looking at logcat I see the following:

```
E/PanoMetadata(17732): Could not read file: /data/data/com.myapp.android/files/downloads/Splash.png
E/PanoMetadata(17732): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.myapp.android/files/downloads/Splash.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
E/PanoMetadata(17732):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
E/PanoMetadata(17732):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
```

Note the "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

But the file is really there and I can display it using my activity A without a problem.

The problem seems to be that the other activity which starts using ACTION_VIEW (in this case Gallery) seems to run under different process/user so it does not have read access to my file.

My 3 questions are:

1. Is it possible to get the ACTION_VIEW activity to run within my process and user context (of activity A)?
2. How do I share files between activities? (I do not like to copy the file under /sdcard/... but if that is the only option than it will have to be.)
3. Is there a way to pass the file content (not file pointer) from my activity to the Gallery activity or other activities?

Regards!

Comment: I am not sure if this is the exact answer you are looking for but have you looked at Content Providers in Android. That's a way for your application to share it's data with other application.

Comment: Why not put the files on the external storage (aka SD card)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the ACTION_VIEW activity to run within my process and user context (of activity A)?

No, nor would you want it to, for security reasons.

> How do I share files between activities?

This question is the same as your next one, as far as I can tell.

> Is there a way to pass the file content (not file pointer) from my activity to the Gallery activity or other activities?

The best solution is to use a `ContentProvider`. The simplest solution is to [use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), which you can just add to your manifest and configure to serve up your files, without any need to create a subclass. See also: http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html

Comment: FileProvider worked out very nicely! Shared my app subfolder and worked out beautifully. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An app can't acces the private data of another app. Being that way, "Gallery" can't reach "data/data/com.myapp.android/files". You need to put the shared files directory in the external storage.